# How to config front end links of express.js (nodejs) Web App running in a subdirectory

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am currently learning a node.js crash course from youtube.

And I use cloud based vs code server on a docker platform to try the code from the author.

So when I execute the source App.js code, the URL will be redirected as below:

http://localhost:3000/

to

http://localhost/proxy/3000/

This redirection breaks the code because the links to different pages uses the base directory like "/" , "/about", "/styles.css"

And those items are reside in the nav.ejs and head.ejs as below:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
  <title>Blog Ninja | <%= title %></title>
</head>


>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
<nav>
  <div class="site-title">
    <a href=""><h1>Blog Ninja</h1></a>
    <p>A Net Ninja Site</p>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Blogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blogs/create">New Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I learn from another post of stackoverflow to create a config.js like:

```js
module.exports = {
    baseUrl: '/proxy/3000/',
 
    setBaseUrl: function (url) {
        this.baseUrl = url;
    },
    getBaseUrl: function () {
        return this.baseUrl;
    }
}
```

But then I still need to distribute this config variable everywhere...

Another stupid approach is repeating to hardcode the URL like href="/proxy/3000/about" in multiple occurance, which is bad.

Are there any solution that is more clean to define every page and static files link that considers the subdirectory situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but you can keep the original router and add a second router that uses the original router if there is a /proxy/3000 url. Then you can use that second url for your app instead of the original one.

You can also use the config variable as shown.

```js
const config = require('./config.js');

var app = express();

var originalRouter = express.Router();

originalRouter.get('/about', function(req, res) {
  res.send('about stuff!!');
});

originalRouter.get('/styles.css', function(req, res) {
  res.send('a');
});

var baseRouter = express.Router();

baseRouter.use('/proxy/3000', originalRouter);

app.use(config.baseUrl, baseRouter);
```